# Why are the SHA256 hashes used by AppLocker different to other generators?

Tags: windows-7

The SHA256 hashes displayed/exported by AppLocker are different to the hashes generated by other tools.

Can anyone explain why?

Example: [Putty.exe 0.62](http://www.oldapps.com/putty.php?old_putty=7007).

- **[Random online tool](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm)**: d4ffa4559a1e22167933772d82cf714cd4bb7a0e79511c2424e18bdb619d63a4

  **AppLocker on Windows 7**: E0517EA6C2896CAA97D6CBF4E8CAEA00409F03703E888E83CFBC460F7682F337

I'm using the PowerShell cmdlet Get-AppLockerFileInformation to retrieve the AppLocker hash here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *E051...* hash you're seeing is not a SHA256 hash. It's an [Authenticode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/hh994614.aspx) hash.

> AppLocker computes the hash value itself. Internally it uses the SHA2 Authenticode hash for Portable Executables (Exe and Dll) and Windows Installers and a SHA2 flat file hash for the rest.

It seems `Putty.exe` is not digitally signed. Nevertheless, AppLocker – having established that the file is an executable, is calculating the Authenticode Hash.

For details on how the hash is calculated, see **Calculating the PE Image Hash** in [this Microsoft document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/Authenticode_PE.docx).

Now as to *why* AppLocker (or, more likely, the cmdlet itself) claims this is a SHA256 hash is a mystery. It may well be a cosmetic bug.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I just tested - for a non-exe AppLocker does indeed generate the same hash as any other SHA256 hashing tool.